# Menu having options in multiple columns on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have been using CSS for multi-column view styles for mega menu. Right now the menu is showing the submenu items in multi-column but the issue I am facing is those submenu items get started in new column although there exists sufficient space in the earlier column.

i.e. For example, I have 31 submenu options and per column 12 submenu items can be listed. Hence it should display like 12 menu items in column 1, another 12 in column 2 and rest in column 3. But, due to some unknown reason. It shows only 10 sub menu items in columns 2 and rest in column 3.

You can review the same via image preview using the below link :
http://prntscr.com/oe22lu

We worked on to implement few CSS scripts to make the submenu items visible as we needed.

```
<div class="main-megamenu notmobile">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-id="23">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="/easy-servo-products" role="button">
            <span class="category-name">EASY SERVO PRODUCTS</span>
        </a>
        <div class="catlevel-1">
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="nav-items menu-options">
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown" data-id="24">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="/easy-servo-motors" role="button">
                            <span class="category-name">Easy Servo Motors</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown" data-id="40">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="/2-phase" role="button">
                            <span class="category-name">2 Phase</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="42">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/hybrid-stepper-motor-2">
                            <span class="category-name">Hybrid Stepper Motor</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-items menu-options-details">
                    <div class="submenu-details-wrapper" id="submenu-details-wrapper-24" style="min-height: auto;">
                        <div class="submenu-details" id="submenu-details-24">
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="25">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/low-vdc-input">
                                    <span class="category-name">Low VDC Input</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-25">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="51">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/2-phase-nema-14">
                                            <span class="category-name">2 Phase NEMA 14</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="52">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/2-phase-nema-16">
                                            <span class="category-name">2 Phase NEMA 16</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="53">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/vdc-or-transformer-input">
                                            <span class="category-name">VDC or Transformer Input</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="54">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/220230-vac-input">
                                            <span class="category-name">220/230 VAC Input</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="61">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/budge-stepper-drives">
                                            <span class="category-name">Budge Stepper Drives</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="62">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/motor-extension-cables">
                                            <span class="category-name">Motor Extension Cables</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="27">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/120-230-vac-input">
                                    <span class="category-name">120 / 230 VAC Input</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-27">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="57">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/digital-stepper-drives">
                                            <span class="category-name">Digital Stepper Drives</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="58">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/classic-stepper-drives">
                                            <span class="category-name">Classic Stepper Drives</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="59">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/stepper-drive-modules">
                                            <span class="category-name">Stepper Drive Modules</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="60">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/servo-motors-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Servo Motors</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="47">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/2-phase-2">
                                    <span class="category-name">Easy Servo Drives</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-47">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1056">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/brushless-servo-products">
                                            <span class="category-name">Brushless Servo Products</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1057">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/brush-servo-products">
                                            <span class="category-name">Brush Servo Products</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1058">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/unregulated-switching">
                                            <span class="category-name">Unregulated Switching</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1059">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/motor-extension-cables-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Motor Extension Cables</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1060">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/advanced-digital-stepper-drives-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Advanced Digital Stepper Drives</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="48">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/3-phase">
                                    <span class="category-name">Digital Stepper Drives</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-48">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1061">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/110120-vac-input">
                                            <span class="category-name">110/120 VAC Input</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1062">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/bldc-servo-motors">
                                            <span class="category-name">BLDC Servo Motors</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1074">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/unregulated-switching-4">
                                            <span class="category-name">Unregulated Switching</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="49">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/5-phase">
                                    <span class="category-name">High Torque Stepper Motors</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-49">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1063">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/motor-extension-cables-3">
                                            <span class="category-name">Motor Extension Cables</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1064">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/unregulated-switching-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Unregulated Switching</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="50">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/09">
                                    <span class="category-name">0.9</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-50">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1065">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/brush-servo-motors">
                                            <span class="category-name">Brush Servo Motors</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="55">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/advanced-digital-stepper-drives">
                                    <span class="category-name">Advanced Digital Stepper Drives</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-55">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1066">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/classic-stepper-drives-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Classic Stepper Drives</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="56">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/integrated-easy-servo-motors">
                                    <span class="category-name">Integrated Easy Servo Motors</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-56">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1067">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/stepper-drives-with-oscillators">
                                            <span class="category-name">Stepper Drives with Oscillators</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="submenu-image" id="submenu-image-24">
                            <img src="../images/thumbs/000/0000233_easy-servo-motors_370.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submenu-details-wrapper" id="submenu-details-wrapper-40" style="min-height: auto;">
                        <div class="submenu-details" id="submenu-details-40" style="min-height: 217px;">
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown catlevel-2" data-id="41">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/geared-motors-2">
                                    <span class="category-name">Geared Motors</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu-options catlevel-3" id="submenu-details-41">
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1072">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/110120-vac-input-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">110/120 VAC Input</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1073">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/motor-extension-cables-4">
                                            <span class="category-name">Motor Extension Cables</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="nav-item" data-id="1075">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="/brush-servo-motors-2">
                                            <span class="category-name">Brush Servo Motors</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item" data-id="1068">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/brushless-servo-products-2">
                                    <span class="category-name">Brushless Servo Products</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item" data-id="1069">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/brushless-servo-products-3">
                                    <span class="category-name">Brushless Servo Products</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item" data-id="1070">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/unregulated-switching-3">
                                    <span class="category-name">Unregulated Switching</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-item" data-id="1071">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/advanced-digital-stepper-drives-3">
                                    <span class="category-name">Advanced Digital Stepper Drives</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-id="22">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/others-2">
            <span class="category-name">OTHERS</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobile-menu-items"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to show sub-menu items in multi-column vertically, such that additional column is used only if sufficient menu items exist. You can review the same via the image preview - http://prntscr.com/oe28im

Comment: I'd image there is something in there abou breaking a column on headings. We really need a demo with the **CSS**. - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/